# Nav bar background only filling the current width of the the view port

Tags: html, css

My navigation bar is completely backgrounded by the color white when i have the project at max browser width but when scaling it down the nav bar background starts to disappear as it should. My issue is that the background for the nav doesnt autofill as i horizontally scroll at the lower widths.I am fairly new to css and any input is appreciate, see photo for issue.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVem9.png)

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

header {
  width: auto;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, lightpink);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-container {
  width: auto;
}

nav {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.navbar-container nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;
}

.navbar-container nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 6.25em;
  position: relative;
  left: 29em;
}

.navbar-container nav ul li h2 {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-container nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="navbar-container">
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <h2>Correia</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>

<body>



</body>
<footer>



</footer>
```

Comment: Please paste your html and css also.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details.

Comment: @Ammar Sherif Mohammed just tried and the issue persists.  The only fix i can seem to muster is to set a hard width on the nav. I have tried using multiple different width units.

Comment: Please use a [Markup Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) - your HTML Markup is invalid!

Comment: tacoshy right. Your header element must be inside the body tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things that play a role here. I have changed your code a bit. The main reason is that the child element ul is not sufficiently influenced by the parent elements.

In my example I used the flex box model. It is clear and you need less code. Here is the example:

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightblue, lightpink);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  margin: 0;
}

.navbar-container {  
}
.navbar-container nav ul {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 black;  
}

nav {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.navbar-container nav ul li h2 {
  color: black;
}

.navbar-container nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
  <div class="navbar-container">    
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li>
          <h2>Correia</h2>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

  </div>
</header>



</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the code below

```
.navbar-container nav ul li {
display: inline-block;
margin-left: 6.25em;
position: relative;
left: 29em;
}
```

there you set the position to relative, it makes the li element different dimensions from the nav element, so the nav element can't catch the width change of the li element.
the solution is to lower the value left for example to 20em or value
as needed

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

or set `margin: 0` to your `nav`

Comment: If you look at the picture and read the describtion of the issue then you know that it is not a margin issue.